# How do I join two mysql tables with different names? (Trouble using UNION)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a little trouble using UNION. (at least I suspect UNION is the tool)

I have the following:

Table 1: `us_states.us_state`

Table 2: `fex_tax_by_prov.TAX_PROVINCE`

I would like to use one mysql query to return all states and provinces as one result ('region'). I have something like this but it isn't correct.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TAX_PROVINCE as region,
    FROM fed_tax_by_prov 
    UNION
    SELECT us_state as region,
    FROM us_states
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are the structures of both tables? Im guessing they are different columns?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it isn't correct*"?

Comment: "I have trouble", "isn't correct"... You're not very found of giving details, are you?

Answer (score 1):

```
select us_state as region from us_states
union
select tax_province from fed_tax_by_prov
```

should work as long as the two columns are of the same type, and adding an alias (only needs to be done for first select in the `union`) means you can refer to it in a wrapping `select`, much like you have in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
SELECT TAX_PROVINCE as region FROM fed_tax_by_prov 

UNION

SELECT us_state as region FROM us_states
```

MySQL UNION allows you to combine two or more result sets from multiple tables together. The syntax of using MySQL UNION is as follows:

```
SELECT statement

UNION [DISTINCT | ALL]

SELECT statement

UNION [DISTINCT | ALL]

…
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
    (SELECT TAX_PROVINCE FROM fed_tax_by_prov) 
    UNION 
    (SELECT us_state FROM us_states);

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the problem was that I had an extra `SELECT *` at the beginning of the query.
Much thanks your your help people.